# How to type a blank character " "

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, unicode-entry

I need to type a character similar that looks like space, in Windows I would've used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>255</kbd>. But I don't know how to do this Ubuntu... Can I somehow use Alt codes in Ubuntu, or use another shortcut?

Comment: Isn't space a blank character?

Comment: @Zanna In password field, to login

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> or <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>: it's called a non-breaking space.

See [this thread on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1196847) for more info.

Comment: The Altgr + space does not work on all keyboard layout variants like classic ones in my experience, but it will work with the default one. You may want to disable that shortcut by changing the layout variant or by running `setxkbmap -option nbsp:none` because you might type it accidentally instead of typing normal space when typing shell pipe command by some keyboards; e.g. I have pipe character `|` behind AltGr key in Finnish keyboard.

Comment: AltGr+Space did not work fro me, but  AltGr+Space+Space did

Answer (score 4):

Press the Compose key (default <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd> although you can change it using `gnome-tweak-tool`), then press <kbd>Space</kbd> twice.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: Thanks.  Working on Kubuntu 20.04.